# How to append Authorization in an URL?

Tags: jquery

I have maybe a very old question, but have to ask. That is I have an URL e.g `$http://www.test.com$`

And I would like, in jQuery, to append the authorization (username:password) in the URL. After all, the URL should be `$http://username:password@www.test.com$`

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Please don't *ever* submit usernames or passwords using GET requests (passing parameters visibly in the URL).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: ...,
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password',
  beforeSend : function(xhr) { 
    var base64 = $.base64.encode('username' + ":" + 'password');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64);
  },
  error : function...,
  success : function...
```

});

This uses the [jquery base64 plugin](https://github.com/yatt/jquery.base64/)